# How to filter unique values of array object when in comma separated string

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array, where 'data_type' holds values in a comma separated string:

Original array:

```
var getGroups = [
{ id: 52, data_type: "Prices & Volumes,Holdings,Reference Data" },
{ id: 51, data_type: "Prices & Volumes,Holdings,Reference Data" },
{ id: 49, data_type: "Fundamentals,Holdings,Corporate Actions,Reference Data" },
{ id: 25, data_type: "Holdings,Corporate Actions,Reference Data" }
]
```

How to catch, filter and build new array with all unique values?

Target array:

```
var targetArray = [
"Prices & Volumes",
"Holdings",
"Reference Data",
"Fundamentals",
"Corporate Actions"
]

console.log('targetArray:');
console.log(targetArray);

["Prices &amp; Volumes", "Holdings", "Reference Data", "Fundamentals", "Corporate Actions"]
```

Here is a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/grnewkzs/1/

Comment: Do you know how to split a comma-separated string into an array? Do you know how to concatenate arrays? Do you know how to remove duplicate items from an array? Just do all 3 steps in sequence and you'll get the result you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const getGroups = [
  { id: 52, data_type: "Prices & Volumes,Holdings,Reference Data" },
  { id: 51, data_type: "Prices & Volumes,Holdings,Reference Data" },
  { id: 49, data_type: "Fundamentals,Holdings,Corporate Actions,Reference Data" },
  { id: 25, data_type: "Holdings,Corporate Actions,Reference Data" }
];

const values = getGroups.map(item => item.data_type.split(','))
const sets = new Set([].concat(...values))
const array = Array.from(sets)
```

you need to know why and how, or your lean nothing...that's bad.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var getGroups = [
{ id: 52, data_type: "Prices & Volumes,Holdings,Reference Data" },
{ id: 51, data_type: "Prices & Volumes,Holdings,Reference Data" },
{ id: 49, data_type: "Fundamentals,Holdings,Corporate Actions,Reference Data" },
{ id: 25, data_type: "Holdings,Corporate Actions,Reference Data" }
]

var targetArray = [];

for (i=0;i<getGroups.length;i++){       
   items = getGroups[i]["data_type"].split(",");
   for (j=0;j<items.length;j++){            
       if (targetArray.indexOf(items[j]) === -1){targetArray.push(items[j]);}
   }

}

console.log('targetArray:');
console.log(targetArray);
```

Comment: This get's the first entry in each array, not all the unique values of all the arrays.

Comment: but it's still not what the user was asking for. they want it unique for all entries of all all arrays. you are providing unique for the first entry in all the arrays

Comment: Thanks , now array is unique for all entries